# error: invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*' in palindrome program

Tags: c++

This code is an attempt to test whether or not a string is a palindrome. It reads a string of characters, pushing each character onto a stack as it is read and simultaneously adding it to a queue. Then, it uses basic stack and queue operations to determine if the string is a palindrome.

The program blows up with the aforementioned error(s) when it hits:

```
inStack.push(inString[i]);
inQueue.push(inString[i]);
```

and I don't understand why, or how to fix it. The research I have done looking into this error as it applies to my case hasn't been fruitful. I'm fairly new to c++ so forgive me if I'm overlooking something stupid.

The code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <queue>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    stack <string> inStack; 
    queue <string> inQueue;
    string inString; //user input
    int inLength; //loop counter variable
    bool isPalindrome(false);

    cout<<"Enter a word to see if it is a palindrome: ";
    cin>>inString;

    if (inString.size() > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= inLength; i++)
        { 
            inStack.push(inString[i]); //put string chars onto stack
            inQueue.push(inString[i]); //add string chars to queue
        }

        isPalindrome = true;

        while (isPalindrome && (!inStack.empty()) && (!inQueue.empty()))
        {
            if (inStack.top() != inQueue.front())
            {
                isPalindrome = false;
            }
            else
            {
                inStack.pop();
                inQueue.pop();
            }
        }
    }

    if(isPalindrome == false)
    {
        cout<<"It is not a palindrome."<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"It is indeed a palindrome."<<endl;
    }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: inString[i] is a character, not a string.   You should try making inStack a vector of char's if that's what you want to do.  Also, you should post the full compiler message including line numbers.

Comment: You don't understand why you can't convert a `char` to a `const char *`? Do you understand why `'A'` is never going to be converted to, for example, `0x40000144`? Your containers are set up for you to add `string` elements to them. Perhaps you meant to have them accept `char` types instead?

Comment: Your stack should hold characters, not strings. However, the error message doesn't make sense. I am sure it is from the different programm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three main errors in your code.

You are pushing characters onto a stack and a queue that are defined to hold strings.  The string constructor cannot implicitly convert from char to string, since there is no constructor that takes a char.  You probably meant to define them as:

```
stack<char> inStack;
queue<char> inQueue;
```

You didn't set `inLength`; I suggest adding something like

```
inLength = inString.size();
```

after your `if (inString.size() > 0) {` to fix that.

Most important, you use `i <= inLength` (in your for loop condition), which won't work; you should use `<`, since `push`ing `inString[inString.size()]` is actually pushing one character beyond what you enter, which will always result in `isPalindrome == false` since your stack and queue will have an invalid (random garbage) character at the corresponding top and front.

These three changes appear to be enough to fix your project.

A simpler solution to give you an example of how C++ iterators can be used to reduce the amount of code you have to write for these kinds of things:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<char> left, right; // left-to-right and right-to-left lists

    cout<<"Enter a word to see if it is a palindrome: ";
    string inString; //user input
    cin>>inString;

    if(!inString.empty()){
        // add characters left to right
        left.insert(left.end(), inString.begin(), inString.end());
        // add characters in reverse order, right to left
        right.insert(right.end(), inString.rbegin(), inString.rend());
        // compare the two vectors
        if(left == right)
            cout<<"It is indeed a palindrome."<<endl;
        else
            cout<<"It is not a palindrome."<<endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to assign to inLength the actual length of the string and get a outside i gets very big, bigger than it should be and you probably get a segmentation fault.

Try after reading the string to assign the value properly.

```
inLength = inString.size();
```

I hope this helps you.